# Does the new Tasks.Dataflow blocks work over the network?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I was wondering how hard it would be to make the new Tasks.Dataflow blocks work over the network. What would be the best approach? Use WCF RPCs to link the blocks, or use some 3rd party messaging/queue service?

Would I still be able to consume messages atomically? One of the problems I have with SQS is the non-guarentee that a message will be delivered exactly once.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Executing one block using several computers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean physical network (LAN, Internat) - TPL DataFlow does not provide any facilities to distribute blocks over a network, so this network layer architecture and implementation is up to you.

If you mean network of TDF blocks, please see this great presentation which describes TDF basics, simple network design and a demo - [Alon Fliess - Dataflow networks in .NET 4.5](http://vimeo.com/43624461)